# Compound collections in Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, ionic-framework

I am using [this tutorial](http://info.meteor.com/blog/whatsapp-with-meteor-angular-and-ionic) to build my own ionic/meteor/angular app and I got to the point where I remove autopublish and insecure and got into the publication and subscribing of my data. Now I'm struggling with the following:

I have two Mongo collections in my Meteor app in `lib/collections.js`:

```
Players = new Mongo.Collection('players');
Teams = new Mongo.Collection('teams');
```

A player has an `_id` and a `name`, a team has an `_id` and an array of two (no more) players: `["someplayerId", "someotherPlayerId"]`

On the server I have publications currently with the following in it `server/publications.js`:

```
Meteor.publish('players', function () {
  return Players.find({});
});
Meteor.publish('teams', function() {
    return Teams.find({}, {transform: function(doc) {
        var playerOne = Players.findOne({ _id: doc.players[0]._id });
        var playerTwo = Players.findOne({ _id: doc.players[1]._id });

        doc.playerOne = playerOne;
        doc.playerTwo = playerTwo;

        return doc;
        }
    });
});
```

In my `client/routes.js` I subscribe one of my states to these publications so that I can use them in my client side code:

```
.state('tab.settings', {
  url: '/settings',
  views: {
    'tab-settings': {
      templateUrl: 'client/templates/settings.html',
      controller: 'SettingsCtrl as settings',
      resolve: {
        teams() {
          return Meteor.subscribe('teams');
        },
        players() {
          return Meteor.subscribe('players');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now I want to use the teams in my code, but whatever I do I seem to miss the point of getting this compound data in.

This returns an error, because the variables playerOne and playerTwo are undefined:

```
  this.helpers({
    players: () => {
      return Players.find({});  
    },
    teams: () => {
      return Teams.find({}, {transform: function(doc) {
        var playerOne = Players.findOne({ _id: doc.players[0] });
        var playerTwo = Players.findOne({ _id: doc.players[1] });

        doc.playerOne = playerOne.name;
        doc.playerTwo = playerTwo.name;

        return doc;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Somewhere in my template `'client/templates/settings.html'` I want to use the teams, with the transformed docs in it. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, to answer my own question, I did the following which seems to work as expected. Serverside I do the following publications:

```
Meteor.publish("players", function () {
  return Players.find({});
});
Meteor.publish("teams", function () {
  return Teams.find({});
});
```

The router takes care of all subscriptions for all subroutes under `tabs`:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'client/templates/tabs.html',
      resolve: {
        players() {
          return Meteor.subscribe('players');
        },
        teams() {
          return Meteor.subscribe('teams');
        }
      }
    })
```

This results in the same 'logic' when it comes to client side data as the autopublish package will do, but that's okay for now.

Client side I can now do this:

```
  this.helpers({
    data: () => {
      return Teams.find({}, {transform: function(doc) {
        doc.playerOne = Players.findOne({ _id: doc.players[0]._id });
        doc.playerTwo = Players.findOne({ _id: doc.players[1]._id });
        return doc;
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

And use `data` in my templates:

```
  <ion-item ng-repeat="team in teams.data">
    {{ team.players[0] | player_name }} and {{ team.players[1] | player_name }}
  </ion-item>
```

`player_name` is a simple angular filter:

```
angular
  .module('PLeague')
  .filter('player_name', player_name);

function player_name () {
  return function (player) {
    if (!player) return;
    return player.name;
  };
}
```

Things that changed from my question-code are the publications of the Teams collection and the way the client-side code handles the Teams, i.e. the `findOne` gets the players[x]._id.

Maybe this was the missing link.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, your subscriptions are not ready. Instead, what I would recommend is that you use template level code in order to render the team, then render every player on that team. So in your publication:

```
Meteor.publish('teams', function () {
  return Teams.find({}, {
    transform: function (team) {

      // this will give you access to all the players on this team.
      team.players = Players.find({
        _id: { $in: team.players }
      }).map(player => player.name);

      return team;
    }
  });
});
```

Now the document will look like this:

```
{
  _id: '1234',
  players: ['Jeff', 'Tim', 'Steve']
}
```

Then within your template, you can do the following.

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
  {{#each teams}}
    // now since the team has a player array, you can use that.
    {{#each players}}
      {{this}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. Is there a `subscriptionsReady` equivalent in the angular-meteor package?

Comment: Okay, to answer my own question once again ... There is a `subscriptionsReady` equivalent in the angular-meteor package, used in the subscribe: `this.subscribe('publication', [args], {  onReady: function () ... etc.`